# CSS padding property for svg elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, d3.js

I can't figure out how the CSS `padding` property is interpreted for `svg` elements.  The following snippet ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLYMn/3/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>noob d3</title>

<style>
svg{background-color:beige;
    padding:0px 0px 50px 50px;}
rect{fill:red;
     stroke:none;
     shape-rendering:crispEdges;}
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", 155)
  .attr("height", 105)
.append("g")
.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "frame")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50);
  </script>
</body>
```

... displays significantly differently in Firefox and Chrome.  What's worse, neither display really makes sense to me:  the size of the displayed `svg` element (the "beige" rectangle) looks to be significantly bigger than what I expected.

So my question is two-fold: 1) How is the `padding` property of an `svg` element *supposed* to affect where things get drawn within it? 2) Is there a polyfill that will ensure that both Chrome and Firefox both handle padding in the same way?

Comment: I looked around a bit and found this article:- http://davidsbigthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/11/chrome-and-safari-headaches-with-svg.html I will look into it more when I get on my home PC. On a side note, I use html5 canvas for all browsers and works good for me.

Comment: AFAIK, the SVG standard doesn't specify anything like padding, which is why it's handled inconsistently. Just set the SVG to the size you want (with padding) and maybe add a `rect` to make it appear like you want it to appear.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thanks for your comment; I'll accept it as the answer if you post it.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

AFAIK, the SVG standard doesn't specify anything like padding, which is why it's handled inconsistently. Just set the SVG to the size you want (with padding) and maybe add a `rect` to make it appear like you want it to appear.

Comment: It seems like Chrome will respect padding when it comes to drawing based on SVG coordinate system. So, for instance, if you have an `svg` element with 5px of left padding and you draw a `rect` with the top left corner at (0,0), then the rect will render 5px inside the svg element. Webkit browsers like Safari seem to not respect this and will draw the same rect 0px inside the element.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience (granted, still very little as I am still learning SVG), I have strayed away from using padding wherever that I could do so. It was suggested to me when I was first learning SVG that I use margin in place of padding, if possible.

This is also because you can use `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to make the left and right sides of an SVG to fit directly into the middle of the screen.

Comment: +1 for the useful advice, even though, strictly speaking, it does not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wasn't aware that the SVG standard (like I said, still new) didn't specify padding inside the SVG itself.

Now I know...

Comment: In this case margin and padding are not interchangeable. Padding on an svg element actually widens the canvas upon which svg shapes can be visible. For instance, if you have an element that is on the edge of an SVG canvas, then you can add padding that will make that shape not cut off. Whereas margin will just affect the right/left positioning of the svg element.

Answer (score 2):

There is no padding or margin, but you can set x and y attributes such that the elements inside or outside get a padding and margin. For example, if an element starts at (0,0), starting at (10, 10) will automatically give a margin of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I was able to try on firefox and chromium: the specified width and height for an svg include the padding.
In other terms, if you want an image of 20*20px with a padding of 10px on each side, you should set the width to 20+10*2 = 40px (same thing with the height) and the padding to 10px

Note : 20+10*2 : 20 is the width you want, 10 is your padding and you double it because you want it on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can apply padding to *parent svg* elements

The padding as described by the OP actually works – albeit, not as desired.

Outermost `<svg>` will be rendered with padding (won't work for nested svgs).
But: **child elements** (e.g the `<rect>`) won't be re-aligned according to – unlike HTML DOM elements.

```css
svg {
  background-color: beige;
  max-height:20em;
}

.pdd{
    padding: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
}

rect {
  fill: red;
  stroke: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.borderBox{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overflow{
overflow:visible
}
```

```html
<p>Rendered size: 205 x 155 – padding added to initial dimensions </p>
<svg class="pdd" width="155" height="105">
  <g>
    <rect class="frame" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  </g>
</svg>

<p>Rendered size: 155 x 105; cropped</p>
<svg class="pdd borderBox" width="155" height="105">
  <g>
    <rect class="frame" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  </g>
</svg>

<p>Rendered size: 155 x 105; cropped; overflow visible</p>
<svg class="pdd borderBox overflow" width="155" height="105">
  <g>
    <rect class="frame" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### Usecase: padding for fluid svg layouts

So, padding **doesn't work well for fixed widths/heights.**
However, it can be handy for flexible/fluid layouts – provided you're using relative (percentage) units for svg child elements.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

svg {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding:0 10px;
  overflow:visible;
}

.svg2 {
  padding:10px;
}

.svg3 {
  padding:0px;
}

.resize{
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>resize me :</p>
<div class="resize">
  <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="0" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="30" r="5" />

    <circle cx="50%" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="50%" cy="30" r="5" />

    <circle cx="100%" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="100%" cy="30" r="5" />
  </svg>

</div>

<div class="resize">
  <svg class="svg2" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- align path center to x/y =0 by adding viewBox offset width/2 height/2 -->
    <symbol class="icon icon-home" id="iconHome" viewBox="20 20 40 40" overflow="visible">
        <path d="M36.4 22.2l-5.2 0l0 13l-3.4 0l0-16.7l-7.7-8.7l-7.7 8.7l0 16.7l-3.4 0l0-13l-5.2 0l16.4-17.4z"></path>
     </symbol>

    <use x="0" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="0" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    
    <use x="50%" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="50%" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    
    <use x="100%" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="100%" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is open Inkscape (or other SVG editor) and change dimension[image]

Comment: Agreed.  It's best to make sure your SVG images are sized correctly and consistently across all of them.  It's much easier and less messy than forcing it into submission through code.  I also highly recommend optimizing the SVG files as well (https://svgoptimizer.com/).  Most SVG editors inject a ton of useless information into every file (especially Adobe), so this will greatly reduce their size and make them consistent regardless of the editor used.