# SVG overflow in Edge not visible

Tags: css, svg, overflow, microsoft-edge

I came across a problem in Edge when applying border-radius and padding to an inline svg. In this specific combination the bottom of the svg is cut off and can't be shown by using overflow:visible. The following image shows the result in Edge:

[image: svg edge cut off]

I setup a basic example illustrating the behaviour here:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/IIuU109SfZNJFDb8

Example code to reproduce:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     svg {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 40px;
      overflow: visible;
     }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any chance to get the overflow to work in Edge the same way as in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Related if not duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695136/css-padding-property-for-svg-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the padding and to compensate I would change the `viewBox="-20 -10 240 240"`

```css
     svg {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: visible;
     }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -10 240 240" width="240" >
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This would most certainly work but to me it seems more like guessing.How come x and y positions are different?

Comment: what  x and y positions? Do you refer at the viewBox?

Comment: Yes sorry... the x and y positions of the viewbox. Nevermind the example i gave does not have the same height and width.

Comment: As you may know the culprit is the padding. If I remove the padding I need to make the svg bigger. For example if you have a `viewBox = "0 0 200 200"` and you need to  make it bigger by 10, ,you will change the viewBox to `-10 -10 220 220`. In your case after adding the extra space the star was not centered so I've moved it upwards